# ERROR: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON and #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

in PHPMYADMIN i want to call function that was in stored procedure and so i run a query
this is one ,  CALL `funcpara` ('karthick');

FUNCTION CODE:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `funcpara`(IN `uname` VARCHAR(255)) 
SELECT ct.CUST_NM, UPPER(CUST_NM) AS UppercaseCustomerName 
FROM customers ct
WHERE ct.CUST_NM = uname;
```

i was enter a input value for parameter as above query, there was an error shows that was-

Error

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said:Documentation
>
> #2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

give me a solution  if any knows, thanks for advance

Comment: Please add the function code.

Comment: You have an error in your function, but if you don't show your function code, it is imposible to help you

Comment: i added function code ,brother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing `BEGIN` and `END` and the `DELIMITER` part.

Try:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE funcpara(uname VARCHAR(255)) 
BEGIN
SELECT CUST_NM, UPPER(CUST_NM) AS UppercaseCustomerName 
FROM customers ct
WHERE CUST_NM = uname; 
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]